# Struggling with syntax to mock Azure.Data.TableClient.Query()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azure-tablequery, azure-tableclient

I am trying to mock the `Query` method of `Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient` but cannot get my head around the syntax.

The concrete query I am trying to mock is:

```cs
var query = tableClient.Query<MyPoco>(filter: mp => mp.PartitionKey == "abc");
```

My attempts to `Setup` the mock are:

```cs
Mock<TableClient> mockTableClient = new Mock<TableClient>();

MyPoco[] mp = new MyPoco[] { new MyPoco() };

var page = Page<MyPoco>.FromValues(mp, default, new Mock<Response>().Object);

var pageable = Pageable<MyPoco>.FromPages(new[] { page });

// attempt 1
mockTableClient.Setup(c => c.Query<MyPoco>(It.Is<Func<MyPoco, bool>>(
    It.IsAny<MyPoco> => true)))
    .Returns(pageable);

// attempt 2
mockTableClient.Setup(c => c.Query<MyPoco>(It.Is<Expression<Func<MyPoco, bool>>>(
    It.IsAny<MyPoco> => true)))
    .Returns(pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempts were close but they were also masking the fact that you have to supply optional arguments too.

```cs
mockTableClient.Setup(c => c.Query<MyPoco>(It.Is<Expression<Func<MyPoco, bool>>>(mp => true), 
    It.IsAny<Nullable<int>>(),
    It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(pageable);
```